# Script to detect user copying - event?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can you detect a user copying in the google sheet script? If so how? I want to create an event that will check something if the user copies the cell.

Comment: There is no onCopy Event Trigger.

Comment: @Cooper is right. However a workaround "might" be possible depending on how much effort you are willing to expend. If you were to duplicate a sheet and then compare the value of edits made by a given user on the master compared to the duplicate, then you "might" go some way towards your goal. Whether the result would be worth the effort would be debatable.

Comment: @Tedinoz I see where you are going with pasting, but I meant if the user tried to copy anything in the spreadsheet a trigger would occur before during or after copying. The idea is that they would be attempting to paste outside of google sheets.

Comment: @CodeCamper Rightttt.... Um. No can do. Maybe a question on Super User about listening for clipboard/pasteboard events. Maybe??

Comment: Just to be sure, you want to tell when you are using the " Ctrl + C " & "Ctrl + V" method to copy information from a cell. Right?

Comment: @LucaBartolacci Exactly, I want to know when a user presses Ctrl+C on a cell, maybe also when they right click and click copy but that won't work because they mostly use ctrl+C.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Cooper is right, there is no `onCopy` event in Apps Script. Not to mention, that Apps Script and Drive environment are separated so this means that you are unable to add/inject an `eventListener` using Javascript in order to prevent the selection (`document` doesn't exist in Apps Script side). Also, the copy method for drive cells doesn't rely on the selection (In order to use `.preventDefault()`) method. I have tested these paths on my end.

As workaround:

1. You can get the data from the sheet.
2. Display it in a HTML page "within" the same Apps Script project. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/
3. Within this HTML page you can use JavaScript (and import a library using a CDN) and CSS in order to prevent the copy/selection of the data.